# Highlight text richtextblock UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, highlight

I would like to highlight the text while keeping the same formatting: bold, underline, italic ... But I only managed to highlight the text by losing the formatting. Is it correct to get to what I want or is there an alternative way to highlight the text without having to "split" it and then reassemble it?

xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="RichTextBlockText">
            <Paragraph x:Name="Testo">
                <Run Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24">
                    This is a
                </Run>
                <Run Foreground="Teal" FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic">
                    different text
                </Run>
                <Run Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
                    format
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="txbToFind" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnFind" Content="Find" Click="btnFind_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        TextBlock NewText = new TextBlock();
        string toFind = txbToFind.Text;

        for (int a = 0; a <= Testo.Inlines.Count - 1; a++)
        {
            Run runCorrente = Testo.Inlines[a] as Run;
            string currentText;
            currentText = runCorrente.Text;
            text += currentText;
        }

        if (text.IndexOf(toFind) >= 0)
        {
            string[] partOfText = text.Split(new String[] { toFind }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            for (int a = 0; a <= partOfText.Length - 1; a++)
            {
                var piece = partOfText[a];
                Run run = new Run();
                run.Text = piece;
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
                if (a < partOfText.Length - 1)
                {
                    MakeHighlightedParagraph(paragraph, toFind, RichTextBlockText);
                }
            }
            RichTextBlockText.Blocks.Clear();
            RichTextBlockText.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
    }

    private void MakeHighlightedParagraph(Paragraph paragraph, string textToHighlight, RichTextBlock textBlock)
    {
        InlineUIContainer cont = new InlineUIContainer();
        var border = new Border();
        border.MinWidth = textBlock.FontSize / 3.5;
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        var text = new TextBlock();
        text.Text = textToHighlight;
        var margin = textBlock.FontSize * (3.0 / 14.0) + 1.0;
        text.Margin = new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -margin);
        border.Child = text;
        cont.Child = border;
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(cont);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...!

I have found some possible solutions but I can not use them:

TextRange - that selects a part of text;
TextHighlighter - that highlights one or more text ranges.

But how are they used? Help me please..!

Answer (score 2):

To use `TextHighlighter`s with `RichTextBlock`, you can first create the desired `TextRange`s, initialize `TextHighlighter`s using them and then apply them to your `RichTextBlock` using `TextHighlighters` property:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange() { StartIndex = 3, Length = 10 };            
TextHighlighter highlighter = new TextHighlighter()
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
    Ranges = { textRange }
};
//add the highlighter
RichBlock.TextHighlighters.Add(highlighter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no a simple property or method being exposed in the `RichTextBlock` control for your requirement to find the text in the `RichTextBlock` without losing the formatting, you should set attributes on the every text within the `RichTextBlock` to make them have the format again. As a simple scenario, you can also just filter the text by a `Run` object then configure all the text's format.